# VSE Preview Window - Cannot set proxy because there's no option in the preview view menu

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, proxies

I am editing in the video editor.  I've built the proxies to 25%, but this doesn't help my preview window.  The fps is so low and the video lags to where I can't edit my videos.  I cannot find the view settings for the preview window.  There's a view button right above the preview window but there aren't any options to preview the proxy I just made.

I can't find any answers online because everything I find is for an older version of blender.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>N</kbd>, it will open the panel on the right > *View > View Settings > Proxy Render Size*:

[image]

Comment: oh my goodness - THANK YOU.  I don't know why I couldn't find the answer but I spent hours trying to figure this out.  I'm a newbie to software like this haha thank you so much!